# Deep Copy of a _field_ variable

Tags: java, arrays, serialization, deep-copy

I have an object that, when its constructor is called, populates its fields with data from the arguments passed to the constructor.

```
// the public constructor
public Looper(Voxel [][][] body, Seed[] seeds) {
```

Within this constructor I want to fill two 3D arrays, **this.body** and **this.body2** using the values contained in the parameter **body**

I need a deep copy as they fields body and body2 will be treated differently and then compared.

I have come up with an iteration over the body array. Since I cannot run the code on my machine I cannot verify if this is a deep copy:

```
public Looper(Voxel [][][] body, Seed[] seeds) {
        this.temperature = Config.StartTemp;
        this.body = body;
        for(int xxx=Config.ptvXLow-0; xxx < Config.ptvXHigh+0; xxx++) {
            for(int yyy=Config.ptvXLow-0; yyy < Config.ptvXHigh+0; yyy++) {
                for(int zzz=Config.ptvXLow-0; zzz < Config.ptvXHigh+0; zzz++) {
                    this.body2[xxx][yyy][zzz] = body[xxx][yyy][zzz];
                }
            }
        }
```

Is this the correct way to implement a deep copy of a field ?

*Can the fact that the array is made up of instances of Voxel.class be    ignored ?*

Comment: You can create two new `Voxel `type arrays and assign the values from argument. this will make it as deep copy. currently `this.body = body;` this line is not doing the right thing!!!

Comment: and also i suspect that array will have common object shared as values.

Comment: If your Voxel and Seed classes are immutable, you won't need to deep copy them, but you will need to construct new arrays to hold the Voxel and Seed instances.  If Voxel and Seed are mutable, you will need to create copies of each instance before storing the new instances in the new arrays.

Comment: Th efollowing fields exist in the class Looper:
private  Voxel [][][] body;
private  Voxel [][][] body2;
@Prashant isnt this equivalent to your suggestion ?

Comment: @DanielStuart : that i got. but that particular line is not deep copying that is shallow copying. both reference will point to same array object.

Comment: @Palamino all the fields in `Seed` and all except one of the fields in `Voxel` are private - does this make them immutable , since I use no mutators ?

Comment: @Prashant yes I know, the question is if the iteration over the array provides a solution ? `this.body2[xxx][yyy][zzz] = body[xxx][yyy][zzz];`

Comment: @DanielStuart  :   if `body[xxx][yyy][zzz];` this returns immutable object then fine otherwise you have to create new instance and assign field value separately.

Comment: @Prashant New instance of body by using new ?

Comment: Yes , everytime you have to create new  object using new and you have  to assign fields value from object which you are getting through array

Comment: @Prashant I dont understand your second sentence. Maybe you can clarify ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71885/discussion-between-daniel-stuart-and-prashant).

Comment: @DanielStuart An immutable class is one that does not allow you to change it's internal values after construction.  In simplest terms, you provide no setters and none of the other methods exposed result in changes to internal values

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object provides a good explanation of immutable objects